# How to retrieve a field in firebase with user id

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am implementing a **quiz app** in **Android studio** using **kotlin**. I am communicating with **firebase** where I store users who signs up. This is how it is structured in firebase:

[image]

And this is how I save a user when they signed up:

```
   class User(val uid: String, val Username: String, var highscore: Int)

   private fun saveUserToDatabase(){
       val uid: String? = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
       val ref: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "/Users/$uid")

        val user = User(uid.toString(), signUpUsername.text.toString(), 0)

        ref.setValue(user)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "User was saved in the database")
        }
    }
}
```

When a user has logged in and have played a round I want to retrieve the **highscore** with the current users **userId** and update the highscore if the score is greater than the highscore. This is my function that handles that:

```
private fun updateScore(score: Int, userId: String, isLoggedIn: Boolean){

    if(isLoggedIn) {
        var ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        ref.child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.e("onCancelledError", "onCancelled", error.toException())
                }

                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapShot: DataSnapshot) {

                    var highscore = dataSnapShot.child("highscore").getValue(Int::class.java)
                    Log.d("highscore", highscore.toString())
                    if(highscore != null){
                        if (highscore < score) {
                            highscore = score
                            dataSnapShot.ref.setValue(highscore)
                        }
                    }

                }
        })
    }
}
```

But this does not work because highscore is **null**, when it should be 0. My userId is right so it is not that, I do not know what is wrong. Since I am new to firebase I have a hard time understanding the syntax. Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not building the reference to the user's node correctly.  You probably meant to do this:

```
ref.child('Users').child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)
```

Note `child('Users')`.

Comment: Now I get highscore = 0 which is good but when looking in firebase the values username, highscore and uid is gone and it just says siKj4RGquieedylUHJvNMAqfmoV2 is  set to 1. So it has overwritten somehow?

Comment: Your write operation is incorrect as well. You need to use a reference to the "highscore" node directly.

Comment: Okey so something like this:                                 dataSnapShot.child("highscore").ref.setValue(highscore) ?

Comment: I don't think you need to have `.ref` in there.